# Giving more weight to existence of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to learn and write elasticsearch queries. I realized that there is a "exists" field that returns documents of specified field exists or not. To learn that I write a simple query and I want to learn more and play with the query structure.

I have a query that simply checks at least one of the specified fields are existing or not. However, I want to give more weight to one field. Here it is my query:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "minimum_should_match" : 1,
  "should": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "geo"
      }
    },
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "location"
      }
    }
  ]
   "size": 100
}
```

I want to get all documents that have the geo field first (for example there are 30 documents that contains location field), and the remaining 70 (size - documents exists geo field) will document that contains location fields (other should).  Thus, the existence of the location field's weight is less than geo existence for my case.

I tried boost for that and it did not work for my case when I do;

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "minimum_should_match" : 1,
  "should": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "geo",
        "boost": 5 
      }
    },
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "location"
      }
    }
  ]
   "size": 100
}
```

When I change the minimum_should_match to 2, it only returns documents that exist geo field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "geo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "location"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "_source": [
    "geo", "location"
  ],
  "size": 100
}
```

This gives below result;

```
 {
    "_index": "mentions",
    "_type": "post",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 2,
    "_source": {
      "geo": {
        "lon": XXX,
        "lat": XXX
      },
      "location": "California, USA"
    }
  },

{
    "_index": "mentions",
    "_type": "post",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "location": "Berlin, Germany"
    }
  }
```

The first one's functions score is 2 because it has a geo field but, the second one does not.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use boost for this case. Use sort instead:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "minimum_should_match" : 1,
    "should": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "geo"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "location"
        }
      }
    ]
  "size": 100
  }
},
"sort" : [
  { "geo" : {"order" : "asc"}},
  { "location" : {"order" : "asc"}}
]
```

This way you will get results sorted (first will be documents with geo field and than documents with location field)